# Set h5 for label in html

Tags: html, label

I have label in html page.

```
  <label class="col-lg-6 control-label">something</label>
```

How can i give h5 feature for label text ?

Comment: If something is both a sub-sub-sub-sub heading *and* a label for a form control, then you are probably doing something wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you exactly mean by h5 feature ? 
Please elaborate and provide more information.

(Assuming you are talking about styling it like h5)

You can use css to style your label as you like .

```
 label.control-label{
    font-size: 13px;
    color:#666;
    padding:5px;
    display:block;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should use h5 directly instead of label, labels are used with input fields and we set 'for' attribute on them to link with input fields, since you does not have any input field you can directly use h5.

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this
    `<h5><label class="col-lg-6 control-label">something</label></h5>`
or this
    `<label class="col-lg-6 control-label"><h5>something</h5></label>`

Comment: Only the first approach is valid. Neither makes a great deal of sense.

Answer (score 0):

Late to the game here... But I just had the same issue pop up (and I ran a search online before trying anything myself). Though, I didn't want to use custom css to solve it, and so I came up with this solution:

```
<h5><label for="myFormControlName">My header</label></h5>
```

Worked like a charm.